# Work with twitter JSON responses

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, twitter

I'm working with Twitter API and python and I'm facing a problem when I try to merge JSON pages that I retrieve.

The structure of the JSON retrieved for each request is:

```
{
  "previous_cursor": 0,
  "previous_cursor_str": "0",
  "next_cursor": 1333504313713126852,
  "users": [
        {
          "foo": "bar",
          "foo": "bar",
          "foo": "bar",
          "foo": "bar",
          "foo": "bar"
         },
         {
          "foo": "bar",
          "foo": "bar",
          "foo": "bar",
          "foo": "bar",
          "foo": "bar"
         },
         {
          "foo": "bar",
          "foo": "bar",
          "foo": "bar",
          "foo": "bar",
          "foo": "bar"
         }
     ],
     "next_cursor_str": "1333504313713126852"
}
```

And I need to merge all the data in one list contaning each user information. THe problem is that when I do it I get this structure:

```
friends_list = [friends_list, raw_friends_list['users']]

[
    {"foo": "bar","foo": "bar"}
    {"foo": "bar","foo": "bar"}
    {"foo": "bar","foo": "bar"}
]
[
    {"foo": "bar","foo": "bar"}
    {"foo": "bar","foo": "bar"}
    {"foo": "bar","foo": "bar"}
]
```

Instead of:

```
[
    {"foo": "bar","foo": "bar"}
    {"foo": "bar","foo": "bar"}
    {"foo": "bar","foo": "bar"}
    {"foo": "bar","foo": "bar"}
    {"foo": "bar","foo": "bar"}
    {"foo": "bar","foo": "bar"}
]
```

Does anyone know a proper way to achieve this with python?

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
friends_list.extend(raw_friends_list['users'])
```